# bash recursion seems to stop for no reason

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I am trying to write a script that does this:
Suppose, I have a directory named `testdir` that looks like this:

```
**testdir**/
├── **jfjfjddsdsdsds** (directory)
├── jfjfjfjf (file)
├── kdskskk  
├── kkkkkkkkk
├── **sadadasad**
│   ├── assd
│   ├── **kakak**
│   ├── **ksja**
│   ├── **lklksl**
│   └── lskal
└── **skdjsjlsj**
    ├── **djfldjlfjd**
    │   ├── eiuru
    │   ├── rhhrhshs
    │   ├── rhrhshs
    │   └── shhdshsd
    ├── jjskskk
    ├──** kdjskdjfks**
    ├── kjjrjjrj
    └── kjskjd
```

The file names are completely random
I want to write a script, that takes a directory path and renames every subdirectory and every file to look like this:

```
**testdir**/
├── **dir1**
├── file1
├── file2  
├── file3
├── **dir2**
│   ├── file1 
│   ├── **dir1**
│   ├── **dir2**
│   ├── **dir3**
│   └── file2
└── **dir3**
    ├── **dir1**
    │   ├── file1
    │   ├── file2
    │   ├── file3
    │   └── file4
    ├── file1
    ├──** dir2**
    ├── file2
    └── file3
```

So it renames every directory in order - first one becomes "dir1", second one "dir2", etc. Same for files - "file1", "file2", and it also writes the depth of a file from the beginning directory. And it should be done recursively for every directory, resetting the "file counter" and "directory counter" in the process.

My script looks like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
#see executed comands when run
set -xeuo pipefail

rename() {
    # $1 - directory path, $2 - directory depth

    fileCounter=1
    dirCounter=1
    #enter a directory
    cd "$1"
    for file in *
    do
        if [[ -f "$file" ]]
        then
            #if its a regular file, write its depth and rename it
            echo "(I am file, my depth is $2)" > "$file"
            mv "$file" "file$fileCounter" 2>/dev/null
            #increase the counter
            (( fileCounter++ ))     
        elif [[ -d "$file" ]]
        then
            #its a directory - rename and call recursion
            mv "$file" "dir$dirCounter" 2>/dev/null
            #call recursion with depth + 1
            rename "dir$dirCounter" "(( $2 + 1 ))"
            #increase the counter
            (( dirCounter++ ))
        #else
            #do nothing, its not a regular file or a directory
        fi
    done

}


if [[ $# -gt 1 ]] 
then
    echo "Too many arguments >:(" 
    exit 1
fi

if [[ ! -d "$1" ]]
then
    echo "The directory doesn't exist"
    exit 1
fi
#start recursion
rename "$1" 0
```

however, when i execute the script, it seems to stop after the first recursive call, so i get the output like this:

```
+ [[ 1 -gt 1 ]]
+ [[ ! -d testdir/ ]]
+ rename testdir/ 0
+ fileCounter=1
+ dirCounter=1
+ cd testdir/
+ for file in *
+ [[ -f jfjfjddsdsdsds ]]
+ echo '(I am file, my depth is 0)'
+ mv jfjfjddsdsdsds file1
+ ((  fileCounter++  ))
+ for file in *
+ [[ -f jfjfjfjf ]]
+ echo '(I am file, my depth is 0)'
+ mv jfjfjfjf file2
+ ((  fileCounter++  ))
+ for file in *
+ [[ -f kdskskk ]]
+ [[ -d kdskskk ]]
+ mv kdskskk dir1
+ rename dir1 '(( 0 + 1 ))'
+ fileCounter=1
+ dirCounter=1
+ cd dir1
+ for file in *
+ [[ -f * ]]
+ [[ -d * ]]
+ ((  dirCounter++  ))
+ for file in *
+ [[ -f kkkkkkkkk ]]
+ [[ -d kkkkkkkkk ]]
+ for file in *
+ [[ -f sadadasad ]]
+ [[ -d sadadasad ]]
+ for file in *
+ [[ -f skdjsjlsj ]]
+ [[ -d skdjsjlsj ]]
```

and the tree looks like this:

```
testdir/
├── dir1
├── file1
├── file2
├── kkkkkkkkk
├── sadadasad
│   ├── assd
│   ├── kakak
│   ├── ksja
│   ├── lklksl
│   └── lskal
└── skdjsjlsj
    ├── djfldjlfjd
    │   ├── eiuru
    │   ├── rhhrhshs
    │   ├── rhrhshs
    │   └── shhdshsd
    ├── jjskskk
    ├── kdjskdjfks
    ├── kjjrjjrj
    └── kjskjd
```

So the script doesn't proceed with the recursion and even doesn't rename all of the regular files in the most upper directory

**I cant see the mistake in my script, why does recursion stop?**

Comment: fyi ... the variables `fileCounter` and `dirCounter` are currently defined 'globally'; this means that each time they are changed said change will be seen at all levels of recursion; depending on how your code is written this could show up in your final results as a) gaps in numbering at a given level and/or b) files/dirs disappearing (eg, `mv a file1; mv b file1` will result in a single file named `file1`); you'll likely want to redefine those variables as 'local' (eg, `local fileCounter=1; local dirCounter=1`) so that each recursion call gets its own set of variables

Answer (score 2):

> why does recursion stop?

Because after you descend `cd "$1"` you do not `cd` out of it.

An easy dirty fix would be to run `( rename "dir$dirCounter" "(( $2 + 1 ))" )` in a subshell. You might be also interested in `pushd` and `popd`. Or you may pass the current depth of the directory location as another `rename` argument. I would do that last option, as `cd` depends on a global state - current directory - which is why it gets confusing.